# "'Calloc 'could not allocate memory" in 64-bit R

Tags: r, memory, party

I'm on Windows Server 2012 (64-bit) with 30.5 GB of RAM, running R v3.1.2 in RStudio 0.98, and am still having trouble with R hitting a memory limit.

I reviewed the FAQ here: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#There-seems-to-be-a-limit-on-the-memory-it-uses_0021

Which states that the memory limit on 64-bit instances defaults to the total amount of RAM, and that the limit can be checked and set using memory.limit().

A call to `memory.limit()` returns `31249`, confirming that it's able to see and use all 30 gigs.

However, when I make a modeling call on a large dataset (~10M rows):

```
ctree(as.formula(formula), data=d, control=ctree_control(mincriterion=0.9, minbucket=1000))
```

I get the following error:

```
'Calloc' could not allocate memory (18446744073673801728 of 8 bytes)
```

But looking at the system task manager I can see that over 25GB is still available, and that R is only using 2.3GB.

Running the modeling outside of RStudio and in R directly yields the same result, so RStudio isn't the variable.

I'm perplexed - why does R refuse to use all my memory?

Comment: That's not likely a memory limit error, unless you really expect that function to try and allocate 16,384 petabytes of memory. It's probably a bug in the C code of the ctree function.

Comment: Many of the modeling calls create multiple copies of the dataset passed to them.  Not a bug so much as inefficient code.

Comment: Bummer. So looks like ctree just won't work on large datasets. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was a bug in the C code underlying the `ctree()` function (as correctly suspected by @JoshuaUlrich). The reason was an integer overflow that has been fixed now in the `libcoin` package version 1.0-2 that the `partykit` package builds on.

(*Comments:* We didn't learn about this bug earlier because the `party` tag was not used for the question here on StackOverflow and the problem was not reported to the package maintainer until today. Thanks to Kris Joanidis who reported the problem and also provided a patch, very much appreciated.)

Comment: Ran into similar Calloc error with partykit::ctree training on 60k x 22 matrix. Wonder if partykit will be patched soon? My version is partykit_1.2-2.

Comment: Pls ignore my previous question. Updated packages, and the error is gone.