# Removing NAs from a large dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, subset, tidyr

I have a very large dataframe, with number of rows = 10 703 009. I want to remove NAs but getting this error, 'Colloc couldnot allocate memory of 10703009 bytes.
My input dataframe is 'a' with many rows with NAs,

| IDs | Codes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C493 |
| 1 | NA |
| 2 | E348 |
| 3 | NA |

I need a output with rows without NAs

| IDs | Codes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C493 |
| 2 | E348 |

I tried both, but getting memory error,

```
drop_na(a,Codes)
subset(a,Codes)
```

Please suggest the solution to this in R.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/27975385/5784831?

Comment: try data.table and dt <- dt[ !(is.na(Code)),]    ... or split the data into a list of length, say, 10 with each 10 pct of the data and use lapply on the list. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

A frame of 10,703,009 lines is no problem for R. See below. I generated a `tibble` with exactly the number of lines where the variable `Codes` contains `NA` with a probability of `probNA = 0.3`.

```
library(tidyverse)

n=10703009
probNA = 0.3


df = tibble(IDs = 1:n,  
            Codes = paste0(sample(LETTERS[1:10], n, replace = TRUE), 
                           sample(100:999, n, replace = TRUE))) %>% 
  mutate(Codes = ifelse(sample(c(T,F), n, replace = TRUE, 
                               prob = c(probNA, 1-probNA)), NA, Codes))

df
```

output

```
# A tibble: 10,703,009 x 2
     IDs Codes
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 I586 
 2     2 A188 
 3     3 H674 
 4     4 D641 
 5     5 A793 
 6     6 B455 
 7     7 B837 
 8     8 A805 
 9     9 NA   
10    10 E380 
# ... with 10,702,999 more rows
```

The size of such a `tibble` is `object.size (df)` return `12 894 1096 bytes`.

We will try to get rid of the lines with NA values.

```
df %>% filter(!is.na(Codes))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 7,490,809 x 2
     IDs Codes
   <int> <chr>
 1     1 I586 
 2     2 A188 
 3     3 H674 
 4     4 D641 
 5     5 A793 
 6     6 B455 
 7     7 B837 
 8     8 A805 
 9    10 E380 
10    11 C231 
# ... with 7,490,799 more rows
```

Now let's replace all NA values with an empty string.

```
df %>% mutate(Codes = ifelse(is.na(Codes), "", Codes))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 10,703,009 x 2
     IDs Codes 
   <int> <chr> 
 1     1 "I586"
 2     2 "A188"
 3     3 "H674"
 4     4 "D641"
 5     5 "A793"
 6     6 "B455"
 7     7 "B837"
 8     8 "A805"
 9     9 ""    
10    10 "E380"
# ... with 10,702,999 more rows
```

As you can see, everything works smoothly and without any problems.